# I have a site that is translated in English and French - can't change "Home" link in menu

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

My entire Drupal 8 site has been translated except I can't find where to change the translation of the "Home" link. When the site is in French mode (with the /fr) all my menu items show the appropriate French translation except for "Home" which I would like to read "Accueil" when I've switched to French. 
Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the "Home" menu link is coming from the UI text in Drupal Core.

You should be able to enable the "Interface Translation (locale)" module and then obtain **.po** or **.pot** files for the respective language (as described on the [Drupal.org internationalization page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Language!language.api.php/group/i18n/8.6.x)).

Refer to https://www.drupal.org/node/1814954 for information about editing the .po/.pot files and https://www.drupal.org/node/314231 for info about obtaining them.